# "System" spamming files on my drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have Windows 10 running on an 60GB SSD. Most of the other files are on a separate disk.

When I boot my system I have about 2GB free space on the SSD. Within minutes, it ticks down to **completly full**. If I restart my PC, I have 2GB free space again and it ticks down again.

Here's a picture of the resource monitor:
[image]

Sorry it is in german. *Lesen* means *Read*,*Schreiben* means *Write*.

I don't know why this is happening. I have to restart my PC everytime because nothing works anymore when the drive is completly full (thumbnails disappear, etc.). I am not sure if it is because of "System" or because of "SearchIndexer".

How can I stop this?

Comment: Your going to have to provide us something like WinDirStat (in English) to better understand your disk usage

Comment: Ok I installed it. What exactly do you need from there?

Comment: You really shouldn't be running any drive that full anyway. The problem will cure itself if you maintain the recommended 15-20% free space on it.

Comment: The file in question there is the Windows search index. Windows is probably trying to scan and catalogue your files. 2GB is also a worryingly small amount of space to have free on an ssd and leaves very little space for the wear levelling to work. I personally would try to free up a minimum of 10gb, let the indexer do it's job, and go from there rather than making it repeatedly work in too small a space wasting the life of your drive every time it needs to restart and regenerate itself.

Comment: @Bobface - You run it then provide us the usage information.

Answer (score -1):

Use **SpaceSniffer** to see what **files/folders** use up all your space. It could very well be that your **hibernation** file is taking up all your space.
http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/